# React passthrough context to createRoot

Tags: reactjs

I need dynamically render a react component in the element `#placeholder`. So I used `createRoot`. My app is wrapped by a `ThemeContext` and my `Test` component need to access the context. I found that with `createRoot` approach the `Test` component will lose the context. Is there a way to passthrough the context into the components rendered by the `createRoot`?

Here is my code

```
const Test = () => {
   const context = useContext(ThemeContext);

   return <div />
}

const Container = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const placeholder= document.querySelector('#placeholder');

    createRoot(placeholder).render(
      <Test />
    );
  }, []);
}

const App = () => {
  return (
     <ThemeContext.Provider value={{}}>
        <Container />
     </ThemeContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass through the context into the components rendered by the `createRoot` by wrapping the component with the same `ThemeContext.Provider`. You can access the current context value in your `Container` component and pass it down to the `Test` component.

```
const Test = () => {
  const context = useContext(ThemeContext);

  return <div />;
};

const Container = () => {
  const context = useContext(ThemeContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const placeholder = document.querySelector("#placeholder");

    createRoot(placeholder).render(
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={context}>
        <Test />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
  }, [context]);

  return null;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{}}>
      <Container />
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```